# How to clear in memory messages from ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ for my application with oracle DB as the persistent stroage. There was a queue which was heavenly backlogged and I just deleted all the messages for that queue from the db manually. After which when I check the activemq console, it still shows the that there are messages and i can browse them as well. Messages are not there in DB for sure.Even after restart of ActiveMQ, activemq-console still shows those messages. How do i clear those messages.

I tired to delete temp storage files,but could not locate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting messages directly from the database is a bad idea as the broker doesn't monitor the database for changes. It assumes that it is the only party making database changes. If you want to delete messages administratively then do so from the web console.